# How do I search the question text of my questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

What is the syntax to use for searching the text of the questions that I've posted? i.e. Limit the search to just the questions that I've asked and just the Title/Subject/Question part of it....

Comment: When will SO be able to examine your question and give you a "here be dragons" warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it now in the site search box:

> user:me "phrase that pays"

The search will recognise the `user:me` part as an ego-centric noodling of your own posts.